# slickslider (unslick) responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, flexbox, slick.js

Currently using Slick Slider on a WordPress site.

I have a slider that features 3 columns max, on a full screen - 1024px plus. On a screen size under 1024px the slider showcases 2 columns and on mobile, the slider features 1 columns.

I have built this slider dynamic - therefore their possibilities, there will be periods, not all columns will be populated. i.e. at the screen 1024px plus, the user may have only uploaded assets for two slides, within the slider, rather than three etc.

The issue I am having is trying to make my slider fluid, for example, if the user only uploads 1 or 2 slides - within the slider, these slides do not fill the full screen. I have tried using 'unslick' my setting for the first object. Unless I am missing from the documentation I can not find anything suitable

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
$(slider).slick({
autoplay: true,
autoplaySpeed: 800,
slidesToShow: 3,
slidesToScroll: 3,
speed: 800,
responsive: [
    {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            infinite: true,
            dots: true
        }
    },
    {
        breakpoint: 980,
        settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2,
            prevArrow: false,
            nextArrow: false
        }
    },
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no option to slick or unslick a slider based on the amount of slides. But you can trick it selecting the amount of slides you have, and initializing the slider depending on that amount.

```
// your Slick element
var slider = $('.your-selector');

// slides amount
// it will take the maximum number of slides or 1 in case the slider is empty
var slides = Math.max(1, slider.children('.your-slide-selector').length);

// slick initialization
// for each slidesToShow and slidesToScroll use Math.min so it will take the minimim amount between the slides amount and the defined slides for the breakpoint
$(slider).slick({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 800,
    slidesToShow: Math.min(3, slides),
    slidesToScroll: Math.min(3, slides),
    speed: 800,
    responsive: [
        {
            breakpoint: 1024,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: Math.min(3, slides),
                slidesToScroll: Math.min(3, slides),
                infinite: true,
                dots: true
            }
        },
        {
            breakpoint: 980,
            settings: {
                slidesToShow: Math.min(2, slides),
                slidesToScroll: Math.min(2, slides),
                prevArrow: false,
                nextArrow: false
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

I didn’t tested the responsiveness of the slider itself. The script just sets the `slidesToShow` and `slidesToScroll` to the value defined, or in case the amount of slides is less than the defines slides, sets the values to the slides amount.

Hope it helps.